# How to simulate bidirectional opto-isolators in Proteus?

Tags: simulation, opto-isolator, proteus

I am making a circuit that uses the ***H11AA1*** (http://www.vishay.com/docs/83608/h11aa1.pdf). This is a bidirectional opto-isolator. 
[image]

I want to simulate it in ***Proteus***, but in the libraries there are only uni-directional opto-isolators. ¿How can I simulate this device, or something similar?

I am suppose to have something like this:
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: same as adding a diode bridge to input. ( except for added diode drop)

Comment: Simply use two single LED opto-isolators with the output CE's in parallel and the input LED connection reversed.

Answer (score 1):

how about rectifying that signal
and then use a unirectional opto-isolator
[image]

Comment: I guess I have no other choice if I can't find how to simulate it. But since the voltage has a value of 120rms I think my final circuit is going to be a little bit more expensive  and I haven't investigated how easily is going to be rectifying it